# Changing size of the UI in JupyterLab (desktop app)

Tags: user-interface, font-size, jupyter-lab

I have accidentally decreased the size of the whole UI in JupyterLab (by pressing CTRL- multiple times) and cannot find a way to revert this action (pressing CTRL+ does nothing for some reason).

I feel like I have searched through the entirety of settings section but have found nothing but option of changing different types of fonts, which unfortunately does not fix the issue as the UI is still small just with bigger font.

I'm sorry if this has already been posted before.